# Styling an iFrame with Media Query

Tags: iframe

I need to style an iFrame differently based on if it is loading on an iPad or desktop. I'm guessing this is done with a media query but I cannot find a solution. I need to use on only one style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@media max-device-width=1024{}`? This should get your css working on an iPad and anything smaller.

Also set a percentage width on your iFrame tag, so it sizes to the screen.